# How to combine iterating over each column and groupBy in pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a dataframe with ~100 columns.  In R I have been able to replace each factor in columns 2-100 with the mean value associated with that factor from column 1, using the following code:

```
tmp <- NULL
for (i in seq(2,100,1)) {
tmp[[i]] <- df %>% group_by(df[[i]]) %>% mutate(mean = mean(column1)) %>%
ungroup()
```

An example from a simpler dataframe is:

```
df1:    
Column1     Column2
10          dog 
11          dog 
9           dog 
1           cat 
2           cat 
3           cat
```

Would become:

```
df2:
Column1    Column2
10         10
11         10
 9         10
 1          2
 2          2
 3          2
```

My question is how can this be done in python.  I've tried using various combinations of the dfply package but I can't get it to successfully loop over each column and then output a dataframe that has the same dimensions as the starting dataframe.
Thanks,
Keith.

Comment: Did you meant `df %>% group_by_at(i)`

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that syntax, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:    Column1 Column2
         0       10     dog
         1       11     dog
         2        9     dog
         3        1     cat
         4        2     cat
         5        3     cat
In [20]: df['Column2'] = df.groupby('Column2')['Column1'].transform('mean')
In [21]: df
Out[21]:    Column1  Column2
         0       10       10
         1       11       10
         2        9       10
         3        1        2
         4        2        2
         5        3        2
```

To iterate over columns you can do this:

```
for g in d:
    # Put your code here 
    print(g)

Column1
Column2
```

Comment: Alex, the transform function works great to replace "ungroup (): from dplyr.  But do you have any advice on how to: a) iterate that over every column, and b) return the values in a single dataframe?

Comment: I've added how to iterate as an edit, you need to expand on what you want to return in 'b'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by combining the suggestion of using "transform" from @Alex with some sleuthing of my own, as follows:

```
list = []
df1:    
Column1     Column2    Column3
10              dog     square
11              dog     square
 9              dog     square
 1              cat     circle
 2              cat     circle
 3              cat     circle

for i in range (1,2,1):
  tmp = df.groupby([df.iloc[:,i]])["Column1"].transform('mean')
  list.append(tmp)
dfnew = pd.DataFrame(list)
dfnew = np.transpose(dfnew)
```

The output should be:

```
dfnew:    
Column1     Column2    Column3
10              10          10
11              10          10
 9              10          10
 1               2           2
 2               2           2
 3               2           2
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for-loop to do it. `across` can handle multiple columns.

In `R`:

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 = tribble(    
    ~Column1,  ~Column2,  ~Column3,  ~column4,  
    10,        "dog",     "square",  "pizza",  
    11,        "dog",     "square",  "pizza",  
    9,         "dog",     "circle",  "pizza",  
    1,         "cat",     "circle",  "pizza",  
    2,         "cat",     "circle",  "pie",  
    3,         "cat",     "circle",  "pie",  
)  
    
df1 %>% mutate(  
    across( 
        # columns other than Column1 
        -Column1,  
        # calculate the mean based on current column 
        ~ tibble(Column1=Column1, x=.x) %>%  
            group_by(x) %>%  
            mutate(x=mean(Column1)) %>%  
            pull(x) 
    )  
)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Column1 Column2 Column3 column4
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1      10      10   10.5     7.75
2      11      10   10.5     7.75
3       9      10    3.75    7.75
4       1       2    3.75    7.75
5       2       2    3.75    2.5 
6       3       2    3.75    2.5
```

You can do the similar things in python with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, mutate, across, group_by, mean, pull
>>> 
>>> df1 = tribble(  
...     f.Column1, f.Column2, f.Column3, f.column4,
...     10,        "dog",     "square",  "pizza",
...     11,        "dog",     "square",  "pizza",
...     9,         "dog",     "circle",  "pizza",
...     1,         "cat",     "circle",  "pizza",
...     2,         "cat",     "circle",  "pie",
...     3,         "cat",     "circle",  "pie",
... )
>>> 
>>> df1 >> mutate(
...     across(
...         ~f.Column1, 
...         lambda x: group_by(df1, x) >> mutate(x=mean(f.Column1)) >> pull(f.x)
...     )
... )
   Column1   Column2   Column3   column4
   <int64> <float64> <float64> <float64>
0       10      10.0     10.50      7.75
1       11      10.0     10.50      7.75
2        9      10.0      3.75      7.75
3        1       2.0      3.75      7.75
4        2       2.0      3.75      2.50
5        3       2.0      3.75      2.50
```

And of course, you can do it with a `for-loop`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import ungroup
>>> dfnew = df1
>>> for col in df1.columns[1:]:
...     dfnew = dfnew >> group_by(col) >> mutate(**{col: mean(f.Column1)})
... 
>>> dfnew >> ungroup()
   Column1   Column2   Column3   column4
   <int64> <float64> <float64> <float64>
0       10      10.0     10.50      7.75
1       11      10.0     10.50      7.75
2        9      10.0      3.75      7.75
3        1       2.0      3.75      7.75
4        2       2.0      3.75      2.50
5        3       2.0      3.75      2.50
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.